# regex for a timestamp HH:MM:SS?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, date

In a file named `result`, containing this:

```
<span class=timestamp><b>15:31:00</b></span>
```

How to grep for the timestamp?

Here are some tries and their output:

```
> grep "[0..9]*:[0..9]*:[0..9]*"  result -o

> grep "[0..9]*:[0..9]*"  result -o
:
:00

> grep "[0..9]*:"  result -o
:
:
```

Comment: `[0..9]` is wrong, use `[0-9]` instead. (`[0..9]` matches `0` or `.` or `9`.) If you want exactly 2 digits instead of any number of digits (including 0 times) you use `[0-9][0-9]` instead of `[0-9]*`

Comment: For a bit more complex xml, you should use an xml parser. e.g. something like this: `echo '<div><span class="timestamp" style="font-weight:bold;">15:31:00</span>It works !</div>' | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/div" -v "./span[@class='timestamp']"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use

```
grep -o '[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' result
```

to restrict the results to strings which are potentially timestamps — hours between 0 and 29 (as an approximation for 23, assuming 24h rather that 12h AM/PM), minutes and seconds between 0 and 59.

Introducing extended regular expressions allows the match to be stricter:

```
grep -oE '([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' result
```

To allow for leap seconds, 60 should be an acceptable value:

```
grep -oE '([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:([0-5][0-9]|60)' result
```

(they are added just before midnight UTC, but the above allows for  other timezones).

Answer (score 0):

You can just below command to achieve the same

```
grep -o "[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}" result
```